# How to extract a single row from multiple CSV files to a new file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas

I have hundreds of CSV files on my disk, and one file added daily and I want to extract one row from each of them and put them in a new file. Then I want to daily add values to that same file. CSV files looks like this:

```
business_day,commodity,total,delivery,total_lots
.
.
20160831,CTC,,201710,10
20160831,CTC,,201711,10
20160831,CTC,,201712,10
20160831,CTC,Total,,385
20160831,HTC,,201701,30
20160831,HTC,,201702,30
.
.
```

I want to fetch the row that contains 'Total' from each file. The new file should look like:

```
business_day,commodity,total,total_lots
20160831,CTC,Total,385
20160901,CTC,Total,555
.
.
```

The raw files on my disk are named '20160831_foo.CSV', '20160901_foo.CSV etc..

After Googling this I have yet not seen any examples on how to extract only one value from a CSV file. Any hints/help much appreciated. Happy to use pandas if that makes life easier.

Comment: What did you google?  reading a text file?  finding a string in another string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

list_ = []
filenames = glob.glob('c:\\Financial Data\\*_DAILY.csv')
for filename in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col = None, usecols = ['business_day', 'commodity', 'total', 'total_lots'], parse_dates = ['business_day'], infer_datetime_format = True)
    df = df[((df['commodity'] == 'CTC') & (df['total'] == 'Total'))]
    list_.append(df)

df = pd.concat(list_, ignore_index = True)
df['total_lots'] = df['total_lots'].astype(int)
df = df.sort_values(['business_day'])
df = df.set_index('business_day')
```

Then I save it as my required file.

Comment: Consider accepting either the answer that helped or your own answer, so that people searching are aware that this has been solved. +1 for posting the solution you came up with

Answer (score 0):

Read the csv files and process them directly like so:

```
with open('some.csv', newline='') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  for row in reader:
    # do something here with `row`
    break
```

I would recommend appending rows onto a list after processing for the rows that you desire, and then passing it onto a [pandas Dataframe](http://pandas.pydata.org/) that will simplify your data manipulations a lot.

Comment: Need to use glob.